# Bind Service with Altbeacon does not work after second bind

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon

this is my Singleton class to which I can add Observers:

Full class implementation on the following link:

http://pastebin.com/bLpTH4u9

The relevant code:

```
public void addSensor(AbstractBeaconSensor sensor){
    lock.lock();

    if(sensors.isEmpty() && !isBinded) {
        beaconManager.bind(this);
        Log.d(TAG, "Binding+++++++++++++++++++");
        isBinded = true;
    }

    sensors.add(sensor);
    lock.unlock();
}

public void removeSensor(AbstractBeaconSensor sensor){
    lock.lock();

    sensors.remove(sensor);

    if(sensors.isEmpty() && isBinded){
        try {
            beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(myRegion);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
        isBinded = false;
    }
    lock.unlock();
}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    Log.d(TAG, "On beacon connect+++++++++++++++++");
    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

            Log.d(TAG, "++ " + beacons.size());
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
                //lock.lock();
                for(AbstractBeaconSensor sensor : sensors) {
                    sensor.setData(beacons, time);
                }
            } finally {
                //lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    });
    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(myRegion);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got exception" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The problem is that after one AbstractSensor is added, the scanning is working correctly.

After calling stopRangingBeaconInRegion() and unbind(), and then calling bind() again, the service seem to remain in Background scan mode only(I get a list of beacons every 30 seconds).

```
05-12 13:34:39.969 25700-25700/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: On beacon connect+++++++++++++++++
05-12 13:34:42.497 25700-25700/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: Binding+++++++++++++++++++
05-12 13:34:42.502 25700-25700/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: On beacon connect+++++++++++++++++
05-12 13:34:43.728 25700-27614/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 5
05-12 13:34:44.848 25700-27635/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 1
05-12 13:34:46.029 25700-27655/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 3
05-12 13:34:47.161 25700-27672/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 7
05-12 13:34:54.091 25700-27778/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 6
05-12 13:34:55.237 25700-27799/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 7
05-12 13:34:56.423 25700-27817/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 4
05-12 13:34:57.566 25700-27833/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 1
05-12 13:34:58.747 25700-27850/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 3
05-12 13:34:59.894 25700-27873/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 5
05-12 13:35:01.053 25700-27891/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 7
05-12 13:35:02.199 25700-27913/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 6
05-12 13:35:03.354 25700-27930/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 3
05-12 13:35:04.504 25700-27951/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 3
05-12 13:35:05.648 25700-27968/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 2
05-12 13:35:11.405 25700-28056/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 8
05-12 13:35:12.548 25700-28071/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 4
05-12 13:35:13.703 25700-28088/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 6
05-12 13:35:38.580 25700-25700/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: Binding+++++++++++++++++++
05-12 13:35:38.585 25700-25700/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: On beacon connect+++++++++++++++++
05-12 13:35:39.789 25700-28555/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 3
05-12 13:36:24.995 25700-25700/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: Binding+++++++++++++++++++
05-12 13:36:25.022 25700-25700/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: On beacon connect+++++++++++++++++
05-12 13:36:26.224 25700-29401/interdroid.swan D/BeaconSingleton: ++ 6
```

As you can see in logcat, the call on range notifier is very rare after the second bind was called.

If someone run into similar problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be good to post a simplified version of your code in your question so others can see easily.  Based on looking at the link, I see that bind() is being called with the same instance of the singleton repeatedly.  That shouldn't be done.  There should only be one call to bind per object instance.  You should not call bind() again on the same object without first calling unbind()

Comment: Hello, I posted the relevant methods from my service. As you can see I call bind when there is at least one AbstractBeaconSensor and I call unbind() when there is none. Even if binding  and onBeaconConnect is called correctly, the Altbeacon will not scan as fast as the first time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what the sequence is the the lifecycle of your application, but something is causing the library to think it is in background mode on the second bind() call.  You can correct this by adding the following line in `onBeaconServiceConnect()`:

```
beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(false);
```

Comment: Thank you, now it works. I also do not understand why library goes into background mode...